# if the application is not open and we click the notification then the display is blank

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a case like this if my application is open and there is a notification I click then I am directed to the page that we have specified but when my application closes and I delete it from the background, I click the notification then a blank or white screen appears, is there a solution for this case , Thank you in advance

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message,) {
    _MyAppState.navKey.currentState!.pushNamed(
       '/MainPage',
       arguments: manager.setRetrieveNotification(
          message.data['km_faktur_id'],
       )
    );
});
```

Comment: do your notification payload meta data has a key `km_faktur_id` ?

Comment: the `km_faktur_id` variable is useful for holding the id of the notification that I use to display to the next page @BaimamBoukar

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem.  Please share it. Thanks.